# Retrieve multiselect values for all products

Tags: magento-1.7, product, attributes, multiselect-attribute

I need to retrieve all values of some multiselect attributes that each of my products have. I found related posts but none of them seems to solve my problem.

For example I found the code

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('car_options')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

But I don't know where should I get $_product from. I guess it's a simple task, but I am pretty new to Magento and I'm still discovering how it works.

I am using Magento 1.7. Any help is much appreciated :-)

Comment: On which page you want to show your options?

Comment: I don't need to show them, I just need them as inputs of a recommender system that I am designing. A PHP file returning them as a matrix for example or an array would do the work, if it's a possible way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code,

```
<?php 
$productMultiSelectData = array();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*");
foreach($collection as $_product){
    $productMultiSelectData[$_product->getId()] = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('car_options')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($productMultiSelectData);
```

It will give you output like this, here key is product Id and value is your attribute option data.

```
[1] => 'Option 1, Option2',
[2] => 'Option 1, Option2, Option3',
[3] => 'Option 1, Option5',
[4] => 'Option 3, Option6'
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much. (If anyone ever looks at the solution, remember to change car_options by the name of your attribute.